# Setting formula inside onEdit() trigger doesn't work as expected

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheets script that's supposed to serve as a confirmation prompt for a user when he tries to modify a cell.

I have used onEdit trigger and implemented it to ask the user to confirm or cancel a modification. If the user confirms the modification the cell gets the new value. If not it gets it's old value back.

All works well unless the cell contains data. Then instead of reverting the cell back to its data and formula the script deletes the formula and assigns some junk value into the cell.

This is the script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); 
  var text = e.oldValue; //backup text in cell value
  var cell = e.source.getActiveRange().getA1Notation(); //backup cell number
  var formula = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getRange(cell).getFormulas(); //backup formulas

  var result = ui.alert(
    'Celula' + ' ' + cell + ' ' + 'a fost modificata!',
    'Confirmati modificarea?',
    ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

  // Process the user's response.
  if (result == ui.Button.YES) 
  {
    // User clicked "Yes".
    ui.alert('Modificare celula' + ' ' + cell + ' ' + 'efectuata');
  }

  else 
  {
    // User clicked "No" or X in the title bar.

    if(text==undefined)
    {
     SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getRange(cell).clearContent();
    }

    if(text!=undefined)
    {
     SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(cell).setValue(text);
    }

    cell.setFormula(formula);
    ui.alert('Modificare celula' + ' ' + cell + ' ' + 'anulata');
  }

}
```

Please notice I have tried backing the formulas of the cell on this line:

```
var formula = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getRange(cell).getFormulas(); //backup formulas
```

and then at the end of the script here I'm trying to paste the formulas back into the cell if the user cancels the modification:

```
cell.setFormula(formula);
```

However, the result is the one described above. I expect there is something wrong with my syntax. I have tried different approaches however none have worked. Please help me correct this. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe someone has a workaround for you, but your "backup" for the formula will never work because by the time `onEdit` runs, that formula is gone.- the edit has already occured. The only historical data provided is in `event.oldValue`, and it is the output of the formula, not the formula itself.

Comment: You could empty the cell by having 
`var text = e.oldValue; //backup text in cell value;
 e.getRange().clear();
 var cell = e.source.getActiveRange().getA1Notation(); //backup cell number;`
This could stop the problem with the behavior when the cell is not empty

Answer (score 0):

I changed a couple of things to streamline it but still have the same problem.  Seems like by the time onEdit() trigger fires the formula is already gone.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); 
  var text = e.oldValue; //backup text in cell value
  var cell = e.range.getA1Notation(); //backup cell number
  var formula = e.range.getFormula(); //backup formulas
  var result = ui.alert('Celula' + ' ' + cell + ' ' + 'a fost modificata!','Confirmati modificarea?',ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  if (result == ui.Button.YES) {
    ui.alert('Modificare celula' + ' ' + cell + ' ' + 'efectuata');
  }else {
    if(text==undefined) {
      e.range.clearContent();
    }
    if(text!=undefined) {
      e.range.setValue(text);
    }
    cell.setFormula(formula);
    ui.alert('Modificare celula' + ' ' + cell + ' ' + 'anulata');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Cooper. I read about passing a parameter to onEdit but apparently that's not allowed. I could I guess make a separate spreadhsheet as backup to keep as reference and refresh it with the updates on the main spreadsheet but I really wouldn't like to use that ideea :D Surely there must be a solution for this. I'll keep searching.

Comment: or better yet I could have a special column which I keep as backup for the formulas and update it when they change

Comment: Personally I think that many people overuse the onEdit trigger. The reality is that there are some things you can do on a program based on your personal computer that you can’t do your running on the server. If you need more triggers and events then make it a Web app.